# Why is Banshee Miro guide slow?

Tags: banshee

Just updated Banshee to 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 11.10.
Miro guide is still unusable and slow, and freezes.
The play button in the sound indicator menu keeps turning round and round and round!

What's the problem with banshee ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you are getting a bug with Banshee. Delete the `~/.config/banshee` or `~/.config/banshee-1` directory, and try starting Banshee again. Don't enable the Miro guide plugin, if it is broken.

I enable the Dbus Mpris interface in Banshee and the issue with the play botton diseapered.
Is it official that miro guide is broken ?